# "Unable to find PCI I/O BAR"

Tags: kernel, radeon, pci

I am unable to find any resources that determine the cause or solution of the error message that pops up when booting up Ubuntu.

`[drm:radeon_device_init [radeon]] *ERROR* Unable to find PCI I/O BAR`

`[drm:radeon_atombios_init [radeon]] *ERROR* Unable to find PCI I/O BAR; using MMIO for ATOM IIO`

When I check `lsmod | grep radeon` it shows that the radeon module is not in use. I have tried loading the kernel module in `/etc/modules` but keep getting same error. Any help?

Comment: "I am unable to find any resources that determine the cause or solution " See for instance this answer and topic: https://superuser.com/questions/1117/error-allocating-mem-bar-for-pci-device-0x-00-0#:~:text=https%3A//superuser.com/a/1194/276585

Comment: Thanks for the information. It seems to be the case but there seems to be no solution in adding a second video card without this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix a Radeon graphics card not working with a "failed to load firmware error"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416135/how-do-i-fix-a-radeon-graphics-card-not-working-with-a-failed-to-load-firmware)