# How do I fix a Radeon graphics card not working with a "failed to load firmware error"?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

When booting up (18.04), I got the following errors when I put in a 2nd graphics card (Radeon HD5450) and I cannot get the terminal to display onto that card.

```
r600_cp: Failed to load firmware "radeon/CEDAR_pfp.bin"
[drm:radeon_atombios_init [radeon]] *ERROR* Unable to find PCI I/O BAR; using MMIO for ATOM IIO
[drm:radeon_device_init [radeon]] *ERROR* Unable to find PCI I/O BAR
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers as well but there were no effects to it. I am strictly working only with the root terminal which makes things more complicated as well as the fact when I looked into the `/lib/firmware/radeon` nothing comes up except a blank screen with a text at the bottom saying it is a directory. Also checked `/lib/firmware/radeon/r600_rlc.bin` which came up with a bunch of random characters. Any help is greatly appreciated or insight! I will gladly provide information when asked.

Answer (score 0):

The `/lib/firmware/radeon/CEDAR_pfp.bin` is provided by `linux-firmware` package.

If the file is not there, you need to update your system by running

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```